# Nodes do not attach to tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I'm implementing a binary tree to store arithmetic expression in C++. However, I have some troubles with inserting nodes to the tree. I want to insert nodes to tree by parsing element and address.

It crashes, maybe due to that the nodes don't attach to the tree.

Hope you guys could help me solve this problem. Any ideas of other ways to implement a binary tree to store arithmetic expression is welcome.

Here is my program:

```
struct Node{
    int element;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;

    Node(int e){
        this->element = e;
        this->left = NULL;
        this->right = NULL;
    }

    bool isInternal(){
        return (this->left != NULL || this->right != NULL);
    }

    void print(){
        if(isInternal()){
            switch(this->element){
            case 1:
                cout << " + ";
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << " - ";
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << " * ";
                break;
            case 4:
                cout << " / ";
                break;
            }
        }
        else
            cout << this->element;
    }

    bool hasLeft(){
        return (this->left != NULL);
    }

    bool hasRight(){
        return (this->right != NULL);
    }
};

class BinaryTree{
public:
    Node* root;

    void clearTree(Node* t){
        if(t == NULL)
            return;
        if(t->left != NULL)
            clearTree(t->left);
        if(t->right != NULL)
            clearTree(t->right);
        delete t;
        return;
    }

    BinaryTree(){
        root = NULL;
    }

    ~BinaryTree(){
        clearTree(root);
    }

    bool isEmpty(){
        return (root == NULL);
    }

    Node* insertNode(int e, Node* node){
        Node* newNode = new Node(e);
        node = newNode;
        return node;
    }

    void printExpression(Node* node){
        if(node->hasLeft()){
            cout << "(";
            printExpression(node->left);
        }
        node->print();
        if(node->hasRight()){
            printExpression(node->right);
            cout << ")";
        }
    }
};
int main(){
    BinaryTree* bt = new BinaryTree();

    Node* root = bt->root;
    bt->insertNode(1, root);
    Node* n1 = bt->insertNode(3, root->left);
    bt->insertNode(2, n1->left);
    Node* n2 = bt->insertNode(2, n1->right);
    bt->insertNode(4, n2->left);
    bt->insertNode(1, n2->right);
    Node* n3 = bt->insertNode(3, root->right);
    bt->insertNode(3, n3->left);
    bt->insertNode(5, n3->right);

    bt->printExpression(root);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Node* insertNode(int e, Node* node){
    Node* newNode = new Node(e);
    node = newNode;
    return node;
}
```

You pass a parameter called "node" to your "insertNode()" method. You create a new node, and assign it to the parameter.

This accomplishes absolutely nothing. So what? After this function returns, what you did with its parameter will be completely forgotten. Just a distant memory.

Judging by how you're calling the `insertNode()` method, you probably meant to pass this parameter by reference, instead of by value.

Comment: yes, I want ot pass the parameter by reference. But I don't really know how. I thought passing the pointer is passing reference, however, it isn't working this time.

Comment: `Node* insertNode(int e, Node* &node) {...`